# How to prove or tell your user that your Mobile App is not stealing or using user's data in any wrongful way

Tags: android, permissions, privacy, user-permissions

I am developing an app that has to access user's contacts to perform certain operation automatically for the user. But how do I prove it to the users that the app isn't doing anything its not intended to do...obviously without showing the actual code, so that he/she is fully satisfied?

Comment: Does the app has an Internet access?

Comment: Yes. It does require Internet Access

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing with trust is likely to be the permissions. Users are more likely to trust your app if the app doesn't require too many permissions. Particularly things like read & send sms but generally the less the better.

You should also consider adding a privacy policy to the Play Store listing. Perhaps make reference to this in the app, by way of dialog or link.

If your app has to use contacts try and minimise anything else it uses. Also, perhaps let the users select which contacts are used?

As a final solution you could try showing the user a sample of the data you're using.

Lastly your marketing could specifically tell users of your intentions and reasons.

Hope it helps